# Properties of the a set called Map(A)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a problem in the textbook and I do not know what the author is asking for. I picked an example to try to prove there is a case where $f$ ~ $g$ is reflexive but I do not know how to do so in general.I assumed I need to just give an example where this is true since it is a proof that "there exists something".Is this the correct approach? If so should I do the same to show the relation is symmetric and transitive? Can I get tips on whether I have correctly chosen the set $Map(A)$ and a hint as to how I should prove the relation  $f$ ~ $g$ is an equivalence relation?Also the last question asks for the set of all equivalence classes for the relation, which I cannot provide.

Let $A=\{1,2\}$.Let $Map(A)=\{f:A \rightarrow A : Domain(f)=A\}$.

Define a relation on $Map(A)$ by $f$~$g$

if and only if

$\exists b \in Map(A)$ s.t. $b$ is a bijection and $g= b^{-1} \circ f \circ b$

(a).List all the elements of $Map(A)$

Attempt

$Map(A)=\{\{(1,2),(2,1)\},\{(1,1),(2,2)\},\{(1,1),(2,1)\},\{(1,2),(2,2)\}\}$

(b). Prove the relation defined by ~ is an equivalence relation

attempt: Take $b^{-1}=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$,$b=\{(2,1),(2,1)\}$,$f=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

then $f=b^{-1} \circ f \circ b$ so the relation is reflexive.

Prove the relation is symmetric
Do I give an example?

Prove the relation is transitive.
Do I give an example?

(c).Find $Map(A)/$~

Comment: There are two bijections on $A$, one is the identity $id=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ (and it is its own inverse), and the other is the functions which switches the values of $1$ and $2$, $s=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$, which is also its own inverse, since $s^{-1}=\{(2,1),(1,2)\}=s$. The function $f$ could be, but need not be a bijection. You correctly listed the elements of $Map(A)$, and $f$ could be any element of $Map(A)$. Conjugating (i.e. doing that composition) with $id$ does not change $f$, so look at the result when you take $s^{-1}\circ f\circ s$.

Comment: @Mirko So like you said if I apply the identity to any $f$ in $Map(A)$ then $s^{-1} \circ f \circ s$ gives back the function $f$. How do I make the proof, since all I have done was verify that this is true using tables? Can I use the tables in the proof to show that since composing with $id$ doesn't change $f$ then the "there exists" is proven?

Comment: @Mirko Or can I just say $f$~$f$ is true for all $f$ if $s=id$?

Comment: yes, use $id$ to prove the relation is reflexive. You need to look at all $f\in Map(A)$, say $f=const1=\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$. This remains unchanged when you conjugate with $id$, but if you use $s=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}=s^{-1}$, then $s^{-1}\circ f \circ s(1)=s^{-1}\circ f(2)=s^{-1}(1)=2$ and $s^{-1}\circ f \circ s(2)=s^{-1}\circ f(1)=s^{-1}(1)=2$ so $s^{-1}\circ f \circ s=const2=\{(1,2),(2,2)\}$ so the equivalence class of $const1$ is $\{const1,const2\}$.

Comment: For symmetric, if $g= b^{-1} \circ f \circ b$ then note that $b\circ g\circ b^{-1} = f$,so $f=(b^{-1})^{-1}\circ g\circ b^{-1}$ with $b^{-1}$ a bijection. (Though, as it happens, there are only two bijections and each is its own inverse, but I didn't want to use that, as it is not necessary, and it may fail for a larger $A$.)

Comment: For transitive, start $g= b^{-1} \circ f \circ b$ and $h= c^{-1} \circ g \circ c$ for some bijections $b$ and $c$, then $h= c^{-1} \circ b^{-1} \circ f \circ b \circ c$ and note that $b \circ c$ is a bijection and its inverse is $c^{-1} \circ b^{-1}$. If you look at *each* map $f$ in $Map(A)$ this would not be looking at just one example, it would be looking at all possible cases, and would constitute a proof (when you describe precisely what happens in each case and put them together). (You could call it a proof by exhaustion.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion